# How to zero pad a sequence of integers seperated with dot in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I need to shape versions in a specific format.

For instance:

```
V1=1.0.1
V2=4.0.1
V3=3.1.101
...
```

Need to be pad with 0 as follow:

```
V1=001.000.001.000
V2=004.000.001.000
V3=003.001.101.000
...
```

Any idea on how i can do that?

EDIT:

I succeed using printf as follow:

```
printf "%03d.%03d.%03d.000\n" $(echo $V3 | grep -o '[^-]*$' | cut -d. -f1) $(echo $V3 | grep -o '[^-]*$' | cut -d. -f2) $(echo $V3 | grep -o '[^-]*$' | cut -d. -f3)
```

output:

```
003.001.101.000
```

Any better suggestions ?

Comment: I tried using printf and got the error 'bash: printf: 3.1.101: invalid number` before returning `003.000,000.000`

Comment: If you are doing this in order to compare versions, it is unnecessary as `sort` can compare them already as they are...

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[=.]' '{                        # Set field delimiter to = and .
   split($0, a, FS, seps)              # Get all elements and separator into an array
   for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {                # Loop though all fields
     if(i>1) 
       a[i]=sprintf("%03d",$i)         # Update the version number with 3 digits
     printf "%s%s", a[i], seps[i]}     # Print the field
     print ""                          # print a newline
}' file
```

If the version are in bash variable, you could use an easier `awk` one liner:

```
V3="3.1.101"; awk -F. '{for(i=1;i<5;i++){$i=sprintf("%03d",$i)}}1' OFS='.' <<<$V3
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution using `awk`. I tried this trick passing the variable instead of file as input `echo $V3 | awk ..` but I get `3.001.101` as output

Comment: Thanks for your update. Why using `NF` ? Because I have to replace `NF` by `5` to get the expected result `003.001.101.000`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try with `sed` taking a text file listing the versions as input, named versions.txt. I split the instructions for simplicity:

```
# Add '00' before each sub-version number
sed -i -r 's/([=\.])([0-9])/\100\2/g' versions.txt
# Remove '00' if sub-version number had 3 digits
sed -i -r 's/([=\.])00([0-9]{3})/\1\2/g' versions.txt
# Remove '0' if sub-version number had 2 digits
sed -i -r 's/([=\.])00([0-9]{2})/\10\2/g' versions.txt
# Add the final '.000' after each version
sed -i -r 's/([0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3})/\1\.000/g' versions.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Another sed-approach:

```
sed -r 's/\b([0-9]{1})(\.|$)/00\1\2/g;s/\b([0-9]{2})(\.|$)/0\1\2/g;s/(([0-9]{3}\.|$){3})/\1.000/g'
```